# Oracle: If-else function for non-nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

Creating a view, I'm trying to find an equivalent 'if-else' function similar to NVL2().  The values I have coming in are guaranteed to be non-null.

```
theFunction(IS_BOOK == 'Y', 'BOOK', 'SHOW')
```

Comment: CASE WHEN IS_BOOK = 'Y' THEN 'BOOK' ELSE 'SHOW' END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use DECODE:

```
DECODE(IS_BOOK, 'Y', 'BOOK', 'SHOW')
```